# Firebase RTDB queryLimited returning unexpected null

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

Say there is Firebase RTDB JSON like:

```
"lastMessages": {
  "uid1": {
    "chatId1": {
      "i": 1695829905,
      "s": false
    },
    "chatId2": {
      "i": 1695829916,
      "s": false
    },
    "chatId3": {
      "i": 1695829937,
      "s": false
    }
  },
}
```

I have an observer in Swift like:

```
Database.database().reference().child("lastMessages").child(user?.uid ?? ".")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "i")
    .queryLimited(toLast: 1)
    .observe(.value) { snapshot in
        print("snapshot: ", snapshot)
    }
```

Then the console says it is nill as:

```
snapshot: Snap (uid1) <null>
```

While what I expect is to retrieve **snapshot of chatId3** which has the biggest "i" value in ascending order. Can anyone help explain why I got null not chatId3?

Comment: My guess is the orderby and the limited combination, try to remove one or both and see if you are getting the entire list. Firebase should order item, however for some reason Firebase doesn't guarantee that the children of a node will be returned in any specific order when you retrieve them.  (try to move to firestore)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am getting the entire list when removing queries so assume that it is about the queryLimited. And as per [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) the snapshot is ordered ascending in this case(orderedByChild with numeric value). .

Comment: I found that it works as expected when adding queryEnding(atValue: Date().timeIntervalSince1970) but trying to figure out why.

Comment: *firebaser here* Good to hear your found a workaround.  --- Your code looked fine to me at first glance, so I also asked a team mate to look into it. They were able to reproduce what you got, so are now investigating further. One of us will post here if we find anything conclusive.

Comment: Oh thank you Frank! I will be looking forward to hearing back from you/them. FYI you may know this but I got 1 element of snapshot when limit it 2(without queryEnding operator), if it helps you to verify.